Missing Bricks Mask Texture with pbr Material
I am trying to recreate a Brick material where some Bricks clusters are missing.
Real life example here:  
I am using two PBR Material (Brick and plaster) from Poly Haven. I got it working with a noise texture, as an Input for the two textures and an inverted Displacement for the Plaster Material to create depth.

But I want only full Bricks to be missing.
Is it possible to maybe combine an overlaying brick texture with a noisetexture to create such a mask?
Any help or Ideas are welcome!
